# Two table view on same screen on iOS

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm a beginner iOS. My project on iPad has two table view to show two list on same screen. I search very much but i don't find solution. could someone tell me how to do that? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible, you can add multiple sub view controller so make two table view controller and add it as sub view controller on to view controller.

If I do it in storyboard it would looks something like this.
[image]

You can use containerView to make this a lot easier.